# Reversing a 1:many relationship between two tables

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship

I have two MySQL tables `A` and `B`. Table `A` has a member `ref` which is a ForeignKey reference to `B.id`. This makes for a 1:many association between `B` and `A`.

This has been in production for a few weeks, but I'm now adding more features to my code and have realized I got my original mapping wrong. I needed a many:1 relationship between `B` and `A`. That is, `B.ref` should point to `A.id`, not the other way around. It wasn't a problem until now because it was all 1:1 mapping so far. How do I migrate my data to the new schema?

I'd guess:

1. `ALTER TABLE B ADD COLUMN ref INTEGER CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (A.id)` -- add the column first
2. Run the SQL equivalent of "`for row in A: row.ref.ref = row`"
3. `ALTER TABLE A DROP COLUMN ref`

Attempting to do this in SQLAlchemy fails with a circular reference error. I need to do it in SQL, but am not familiar with the necessary SELECT+UPDATE syntax. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For step 2:

```
update b, a
    set b.ref = a.id
    where a.ref = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the foreign key constraint as fourth step, you won't need it when creating the column.